# How replace status for another with ngClass

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I like to have two state in on NgClass.
When the status is true and class success it display text 'On'
When it's false and class warning it display text 'Off'
but if the status error is true , class danger I just need to display only 'Problem'

```
<td mat-cell class="status" *matCellDef="let element" [ngClass]="{
                      'alert alert-success': element.status ,
                      'alert alert-warning': element.status === false
                      ,'alert alert-danger' : element.error}"
                      > {{element.status ? 'On' : 'Off'}} </td>
```

Comment: I suggest moving the logic to your controller; have a `cellStatusClass(element)` function that returns the appropriate class and a `cellStatus(element)` that returns the appropriate text. Use whatever if/else control flow logic you need in those functions.

Comment: Great man , it's working !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working like this !

Html

```
    <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Etat </th>
      <td mat-cell class="status" *matCellDef="let element" [ngClass]="iconDisplay(element)"
                  > {{stateDisplay(element)}} </td>
    </ng-container>
```

Ts

```
  iconDisplay(element){
    if (element.error === true) {
      return 'alert alert-danger'
    } else if ( element.status === false) {
      return 'alert alert-warning'
    } else if (element.status === true) {
      return 'alert alert-success'
    }
  }

  stateDisplay(element){
    if (element.error === true) {
      return 'Probleme'
    } else if ( element.status === false) {
      return 'Eteinte'
    } else if (element.status === true) {
      return 'Allumee'
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <td mat-cell class="status" *matCellDef="let element">
                      <span *ngIf="element.status || element.status==false">
                       <span *ngIf="element.status==true" class="alert alert-success">On</span>
                        <span *ngIf="element.status==false" class="alert alert-warning">off</span>
                        </span>
                         <span *ngIf="element.error" class="alert alert-danger">Problem</span>
                       </td>
```

Comment: thanks, but I jus want replace On or Off by 'problem'. I don't want both

Comment: it will render only one item either On || Off || Problem bcz element,staus & elemt.error will not come together